# Springsource not showing up in - Define a new server list

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource, tcserver

Application using: springsource-tool-suite-2.5.1.RELEASE-e3.6.1-win32

Issue: Unable to add spring source tc server in sts

Reason: springsource>s pringsource tc server is not present in the list

I am struggling to add springsource server in sts. Always there would be option present in "New Server"/"Define a new server" as springsource where I could add the server.

Till yesterday it was added, all of a sudden its not showing up. This has happened twice, googled everything to figure out how to add but in vain.

I have already installed tc server and is in proper location- This was working all good, all of a sudden it fails

[Define new server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioo0T.png)

Comment: this looks strange, maybe an update happened behind the scenes that caused some incompatibilities? just guessing... You could try to open a console view, switch that to the "OSGi Host Console" and type in "ss" for "short status". The output will show you the details of the installed bundles. Is there a bundle (or multiple) showing up with the state "INSTALLED" (instead of "ACTIVE", etc.)?

Comment: Its showing as below. its the same as its showing my another new sts which is in proper working condition
osgi> ss

Framework is launched.

id State       Bundle
0 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806

osgi>

Comment: can you check this with a fresh STS 3.7.1 install? Just to verify...

Comment: I actually re installed sts 2.5.1 and now the new copy is working fine. Old copy is still an issue.

Comment: This could be an issue with additional third-party plugins being installed and causing an incompatibility. Or something else went wrong. Would also be interesting to see what happens if you use a fresh and clean workspace with the old copy of STS - or what happens if you start it with the "-clean" option to wipe out stale cache data. Sometimes that helps as well.

Comment: Tried that too but dint help.  Your first reason could be possible, I installed veloeclipse plugin, from then on it has started acting like this. Now its working fine.

Comment: if you post more details about the veloeclipse plugin that you installed (what version from which update site) I could have a look what is going wrong, but usually there is not much we can do about those incompatibilities (unfortunately). But it could be interesting to see what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Ya that is true, We cannot do anything with the incompatibility. Veloeclipse plugin is used to make .vm file easily readable else in sts .vm is viewed like a normal text file which is difficult to understand the flow. Here is the link from where I downloaded and installed the plugin https://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/

Comment: I tried to install it into a fresh STS 3.7.1 and that doesn't work at all, the veloeclipse plugin is way too old for that version of Eclipse and STS...

Comment: We have to be quite careful about these plugins who totally ruin the STS. I uninstalled the plugin, deleted but the STS didnt get back to normal.

Comment: did you try to start STS with the "-clean" option after uninstalling those plugins?

Comment: I did not do that, I tried restarting but did not do -clean. So do you think it would have helped me if I did -clean. I would try however now too as I have the corrupt version still

Comment: Yes, please try to start with "-clean"